# Javascript SVG with WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, svg, localhost

I'm trying to replicate this: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/07/shape-hover-effect-with-svg/

It works on my localhost but not on WordPress. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say not on Wordpress could you clarify? Is this wordpress.com, your web hosted version of Wordpress or a localhost version?

The first thing to do is check the mime type if you have posted the svg to a web server.

Could you post a url so I can see what the issue is first off, then I can help you figure what to do next to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stefan. It's on a web hosted version of wordpress not wordpress.com. Here is the url: http://s672167600.websitehome.co.uk/

Comment: There is some clash with the styles so you'll probably need to look into that.

But the reason it's not animating is you've missed putting in the Js in the bottom of the page.

Comment: https://codepen.io/stefan24/pen/bRRjeo

If you look at the bottom of the html there is a self invoking function you missed this out.

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/07/shape-hover-effect-with-svg/
Check the last section called "The JavaScript" this is the code you were missing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Got the animation working perfectly. Just need to sort out the CSS. Thanks Stefan.

Comment: When I say the animation is working perfect I mean that the animation does actually move but in no way does it bounce like the demo, it's also a bit slower. Any idea why?

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks again Stefan.